# Why do double quotes break the ssh statement?

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, double-quotes

I am trying to ssh into my amazon server.  I have two ways of doing it, one works and  one doesn't, and I'm not sure why the second one does not work.

## First way:

```
ssh -i path-to-pem-file username@public-ip
```

This works.

## Second way:

```
ssh -i "path-to-pem-file" username@public-ip
```

This results in "Warning: Identity file "path-to-pem-file" not accessible".

Both of the above  commands are run from the terminal on Mac OSX.  Why do the double quotes break the statement? thanks.

Comment: Are you using the `~` for your home directory by chance? e.g. `ssh -i "~/keys/pemkey" derp@wherever`

Comment: Showing the actual path would be useful, although I suspect phpisuber01 is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using shell expansion or other [special characters](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html) their special meanings will not be interpreted when quoted. They are considered literal values.

You can replicate this with the `~` or special character for `$HOME`

**Doesnt work**

```
ssh -i "~/mypemkey.pem" ec2-user@somehost
```

**Works**

```
ssh -i ~/mypemkey.pem ec2-user@somehost
```

Essentially the ssh application is trying to find a literal file path `~/` instead of `/Users/someuser/` when expanded.

Want to see it in action under the hood.... test it!

**Create a simple bash script**

```
echo "echo \$1" > test.sh
```

**Execute it**

```
/bin/bash test.sh ~/Desktop
    outputs: /Users/phpisuber01/Desktop

/bin/bash test.sh "~/Desktop"
    outputs: ~/Desktop
```